# How to set up ListUnsubscribers

Tags: civimail, drupal

What is the correct delimiter for VERP - and how to set up a ListUnsubscribers. You responded to a joomla question - I am using drupal 9.

You indicated checking the VERP delimeter - so what should it be ?

And you indicated to check line 41 in List-Unsubscribers. But what are we supposed to check there?

What are the actual steps to set up a list of unsubscribers ??